# Can't enter square brackets in gfsh

Tags: gemfire, geode, gfsh

When I try to enter square brackets inside gfsh they do not always show on screen and if they are followed by digits the first two are not considered.

If I for example enter `connect --locator=somehost[12345]` this is shown:
[image: shortened to somehost345]

It seems to help when I hit `[` twice because then one `[` makes it to the screen. But it remains impossible to get the closing square bracket `]`.

Please note that I use a German setting and thus have to press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> for the opening square bracket `[` and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> for the closing square bracket `]`.
Other characters work, for example `{` and `}` which I also have to enter using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>. The backslash `\` that I have to enter by pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>ß</kbd> doesn't work too.

I posted this problem also on the [Geode Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-3046).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround it works to enter those special characters using their Ascii value.

On Windows this is:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for the opening square
  bracket `[`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> for the
  backslash `\`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> for the
  closing square bracket `]`

Please note that you have to use the numerical keyboard for this.

[image: Connecting to port 12345]